# What's a safe, green, practical, affordable and effective way to physically destroy hard drives with household tools?

Tags: hard-drive

I've been googling around this, and can't really get a satisfying answer.

I want to destroy the drives (old fashioned magnetic hdds) myself, not give them to a recycling company. I know reputable ones exist... but hell, I just don't want there to be any chance my DEA brother -in-law finds out about the international meth ring that I'm operating, so get off my case, ok?

Some of the articles seem to be showcasing [the thrills and spills](http://www.wikihow.com/Destroy-a-Hard-Drive) you can have with this project. Shoot a hard drive! Melt a hard drive! Blow up a hard drive! I don't really know what to say to all that, except that it's stupid.

On the other hand, I am not going to buy a purpose-built hard drive crusher. It's my understanding that when you smash up a drive with a hammer it releases toxic fumes... I don't want that.

So, how do you destroy it? And what do you do with the bits afterward?

Comment: smash with a hammer releasing fumes? no.  incinerating in your fireplace? yes.  it's just electronics, disassemble and break the platters.

Comment: A couple or three large holes drilled through the controller and platters will do the trick.